# Splitting a graph into disjoint blocks

Tags: optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization

Suppose we are given a weighted graph $G=(N,E)$ ($W(e)$ is the weight corresponding to $e\in E$). Let $d(i,j)$ denote the *minimum weighted distance* between nodes $i$ and $j$.

My goal is to split the graph into **disjoint** components ($B_1,\ldots,B_K$) s.t. $\max_{i,j\in B_k}d(i,j)<a$ for some given constant $a>0$ ($d(\cdot,\cdot)$ here is the distance on $G$) and the resulting partition minimizes $K$ (i.e. the total number of components).

Of course, I can perform an exhaustive search. However, for a sufficiently large graph it seems to be infeasible. Is there a clever way to find such partition?

---

**Clarification**: My ultimate goal is to create a partition s.t. the number of elements in each component is as large as possible (given the constraint) while the variation of $|B_1|,\ldots,|B_K|$ is minimized ($|B_k|$ is the size of $B_k$).

Comment: Is splitting into 1-node components valid? Variance = 0

Comment: @Mr.Newman Oh. You're right. I'm just trying to formulate the problem.

Comment: This can be formulated as a mixed integer optimization problem. You also confuse radius with diameter.

Comment: Is your graph $G$ complete? otherwise $d_{ij}$ on $G$ might be different from the one on $B_k$ ... 

Suppose $i$ and $j$ are in $B_k$...If $d_{ij}$ passes through a node $v$ that is not in $B_k$ then the distance between $i$ and $j$ in $B_k$ can only be greater than  $d_{ij}$...

Comment: @RafaelColares $G$ is not necessary complete. But I evaluate $d(i,j)$ for $i,j\in B_k$ using all paths between $i$ and $j$ which may not belong to $B_k$.

Comment: @LinAlg How do I deal with nonlinear constraints?

Comment: @d.k.o. it is straightforward if you can enumerate the components that satisfy your constraint

Comment: @LinAlg If you use your basis $d_{ij}$ for the evaluation, I don't think you need nonlinear constraints... Please, explain what you have in mind for modelling this problem. Also, on your question you say that you want to minimise K (the number of components) and on the clarification you say that you want to minimise the variation of their sizes... It is not exactly the same thing...

Comment: @RafaelColares $d_{ij}$ depends on the components. Although it is possible to model this, the number of constraints would be enormous and I do not expect good solutions in reasonable time.

Comment: @RafaelColares I believe that minimizing $K$ would be a good approximation which is easier to solve.